# Google short url - max url length

Tags: php, google-api, maxlength, short-url

I'm playing with [Google URL shortner API](https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/), i would like to know if is there any maximum length for the URL returned from google.

I mean, short URLs are called short url because they are short, so they should be at max `x` chars length. I would like to know what that `x` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way of telling the true length of them, the URL's could one day get 1 character longer because they ran out of unique links.

But currently they are 5 characters long, with a mix of numbers, low and higher case letters.

Comment: thank you , i guess anyway they should be at max 6/7 chars i guess they can be incremented but not too much, altought it will be no more short url :D they will be in contraddiction if too many chars :D